# Select from where a value may be null or not

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query

```
select c from DTO c where trafficLight = ?1
```

When traffic light is red or green it returns the expected rows but when traffic light is null it returns nothing. In database there are records with null traffic light. I know that the checking for null is "is null", but what is the best way to do it here? Thanks.

Comment: You want to exclude rows that have `null` as value for `trafficLight`?

Comment: What's the problem in using **ISNULL** clause? You want to return all the records then why you are using where clause?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: There are cases that trafficLight has value (red, green, etc...) and cases that has null value. I want the expression "where trafficLight = ?1" to evaluate all the cases, not only the cases that trafficLight has value. If I write it "where trafficLight is ?1" it evaluates only the cases that traffic light is null.

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks but this query returns all the records that are null or not null. I get the traffic light dynamically and I want the query to return explicit results. If I get traffic light null, I want only the database rows which have trafficlight = null. If I get traffic light red, I want the database rows which have trafficLight = red.

Answer (score 2):

> I want the expression "where trafficLight = ?1" to evaluate all the
>   cases

"*bad luck I'm afraid*"

NULL is the absence of any value, so by definition you if use the equal operator against NULL it will NEVER return true:

```
where NULL = NULL -- is never true
```

as there is no value at all to compare, there simply is no way to know if they are equal or not, so "not equal" also does not work. I do understand this is difficult to follow, but "it is what it is" and try as you might `NULL = NULL` is never true. This however will work for all cases

```
where (trafficLight = ?1 and ?1 IS NULL)

where (trafficLight = 'red' or 'red' IS NULL)     -- true when trafficLight = 'red'
where (trafficLight = 'amber' or 'amber' IS NULL) -- true when trafficLight = 'amber'
where (trafficLight = 'green' or 'green' IS NULL) -- true when trafficLight = 'green'
where (trafficLight = NULL or NULL IS NULL)       -- true for all
```

Comment: The query "where (trafficLight = NULL or NULL IS NULL)" returns all the rows of the database because it not assigns null to trafficLight.

Comment: correct, typically NULL in a variable is used to return all rows, do you want some other result?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, I want to return all rows which have trafficLight = null.

Comment: Then you use `where trafficlight IS NULL`

Comment: Yes, I understand. Because of the cases (red, green, yellow, ..., null), I want something that works for all cases. Something that when I have red, green,... it does "where trafficLight = ?1" and when I have null it does "where trafficLight is null"...

Comment: How are you sending the query to the db? (eg C# PHP Java). You should implement the logic in that product, not in the SQL

Comment: Thanks from answering. From Java. Moreover, I tried select c from DTO c where (if(trafficLight = ?1, trafficLight = ?1, trafficLight is null)), but it does not work... or this, select c from DTO c where (if(trafficLight is not null, trafficLight = ?1, trafficLight is null)

Comment: Raise a java question on how to handle your need. This isn't something you want to do through SQL alone. I cannot assist with Java coding.

Comment: It worked! "select c from DTO c where (if(?1 is not null, trafficLight = ?1, trafficLight is null)) "

Comment: Please If you find the solution, properly answer your question and delete the comments